# For Each c in Range r spitting out error when printing value to other sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

For some reason I keep getting an 'Application or Object defined error' warning when trying to run this loop? I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong? It worked fine as a for loop; but, for some reason, for each seems to be messing it up. there are 10 columns total, but i only want to loop through columns 3 through 9, starting with row 3, column 3. Some cells are completely empty, while others contain text, and some may even hold numbers (not at the moment).

The sub essentially sets the range, while the function is used to actually test the conditions, and, if the conditions are true, place the value of the active cell with additional text on another sheet.

```
Sub Together()
'~~> all variables not shown here are Public variables
Dim cell As Range

With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set r = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(3, 3), Cells(lastRow, lastCol - 1))
End With

        For Each c In Range(Cells(3, 3), Cells(lastRow, lastCol - 1))
            Debug.Print c.Address '~~> outputs '$C$3'
            Debug.Print lastRow & ":" & lastCol '~~> Output is correct: 64:10
            Select Case True
                Case Ready_For_Import(c)
            End Select
        Next c


End Sub

Function TogetherFunc(c As Variant)
Dim SR As Worksheet
Set SR = Worksheets("SR")
Debug.Print c.Address
         If Not c.Value = "" And Not IsNumeric(c.Value) Then
         gives error '~~>   Worksheets("SR").Cells(i - 1, 61).Value = "True" + c.Value + ""
         End If


End Function
```

Comment: (a) You need to tell us what line gives the error.  (b) You need to post code that can be used to reproduce the problem. E.g. what is the `Ready_For_Import` function doing? (c) My best bet though is that `lastCol` is being set to `1` as you have nothing in row 1 of the active sheet, and therefore you get an error trying to access column 0 when saying `lastCol - 1`. (d) No, that would be my second-best bet - my best bet is now the `i - 1` row reference in `TogetherFunc` when you have never set `i` to anything.  (But I'm not seeing how it gets to that function.)

Comment: You have just edited the question to say all variables are Public.  What is the value of `i` when it crashes.

Comment: You are exactly right, @YowE3K. It works once I added a for i = 3 after the For Each.

Comment: OK - so it sounds like `i` should be replaced (in your `TogetherFunc` function) with `c.Row`.

Comment: Done. It works perfectly. Thanks again @YowE3K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved by Yowe3k, though was not submitted as solution. Thanks Yow!

```
Sub Together()
Dim cell As Range

  With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set r = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(3, 3), Cells(lastRow, lastCol - 1))
End With

For Each c In Range(Cells(3, 3), Cells(lastRow, lastCol - 1))
        Debug.Print c.Address 
        Debug.Print lastRow & ":" & lastCol 64:10
        Select Case True
            Case Ready_For_Import(c)
        End Select
    Next c


End Sub

Function TogetherFunc(c As Variant)
    Dim SR As Worksheet
    Set SR = Worksheets("SR")
    Debug.Print c.Address
    If Not c.Value = "" And Not IsNumeric(c.Value) Then
        Worksheets("SR").Cells(**c.row - 1**, 61).Value = "True" + c.Value + ""
    End If
End Function
```